# how to convert this extjs app.js file into MVC pattern of EXTJS

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs4, extjs-mvc

js file here i created three tabs inside three tab's again i created some panels in one file. Right now i want to change this file into MVC architecture for EXTJS. So, please tell me.
    Ext.onReady(function() {

```
    //-----------------------------------------------Displaying Data In Grid-----------------------------------------------
     Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
            fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
            data: {
                'items': [{
                    'name': 'Lisa',
                    "email": "lisa@simpsons.com",
                    "phone": "555-111-1224"
                }, {
                    'name': 'Bart',
                    "email": "bart@simpsons.com",
                    "phone": "555-222-1234"
                }, {
                    'name': 'Homer',
                    "email": "home@simpsons.com",
                    "phone": "555-222-1244"
                }, {
                    'name': 'Marge',
                    "email": "marge@simpsons.com",
                    "phone": "555-222-1254"
                },{
                    'name': 'Lisa',
                    "email": "lisa@simpsons.com",
                    "phone": "555-111-1224"
                }, {
                    'name': 'Bart',
                    "email": "bart@simpsons.com",
                    "phone": "555-222-1234"
                }, {
                    'name': 'Homer',
                    "email": "home@simpsons.com",
                    "phone": "555-222-1244"
                }, {
                    'name': 'Marge',
                    "email": "marge@simpsons.com",
                    "phone": "555-222-1254"
                }]
            },
            proxy: {
                type: 'memory',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'items'
                }
            }
        });

     var columndata = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            title: 'Simpsons',
            autoScroll: true,
            store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
            columns: [{
                text: 'Name',
                dataIndex: 'name'
            }, {
                text: 'Email',
                dataIndex: 'email',
                flex: 1
            }, {
                text: 'Phone',
                dataIndex: 'phone'
            }],
            /*height: 200,
            width: 500,*/
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    //-----------------------------------------------End Displaying Data---------------------------------------------------
    //-------------------------------------------------Displaying series chart in FS Set-----------
/*   var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
            fields: ['name', 'data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4', 'data5']

        });*/
      var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
          fields: ['name', 'data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4', 'data5'],
            model: 'Chart',
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'json/series.json',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'data'
                }
            },
            autoLoad: true
        });

       var series = Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart', {
           //--> if we didn't put this with in comment this chart will be display on backside also for first time loading
          //  renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            width: 500,
            height: 200,
            animate: true,
            store: store,
            axes: [{
                type: 'Numeric',
                position: 'left',
                fields: ['data1', 'data2'],
                label: {
                    renderer: Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer('0,0')
                },
                title: 'Sample Values',
                grid: true,
                minimum: 0
            }, {
                type: 'Category',
                position: 'bottom',
                fields: ['name'],
                title: 'Sample Metrics'
            }],
            series: [{
                type: 'line',
                highlight: {
                    size: 7,
                    radius: 7
                },
                axis: 'left',
                xField: 'name',
                yField: 'data1',
                markerConfig: {
                    type: 'cross',
                    size: 4,
                    radius: 4,
                    'stroke-width': 0
                }
            }, {
                type: 'line',
                highlight: {
                    size: 7,
                    radius: 7
                },
                axis: 'left',
                fill: true,
                xField: 'name',
                yField: 'data2',
                markerConfig: {
                    type: 'circle',
                    size: 4,
                    radius: 4,
                    'stroke-width': 0
                }
            }]
        });
    //-------------------------------------------------End Series Chart---------------------------- 

//-------------------------------------------------Yield Cureve-Graph panel-ColumnChart.json Start Here-----------------------------------------------
 Ext.define('Chart', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['name', 'data']
});

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'Chart',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'json/ColumnChart.json',

        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data'
        }
    },
    autoLoad: true
});
       var Panel= Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            width: 500,
            height: 230,
            animate: true,
            store: store,
            axes: [{
                type: 'Numeric',
                position: 'left',
                fields: ['data'],
                label: {
                    renderer: Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer('0,0')
                },
                title: 'Sample Values',
                grid: true,
                minimum: 0
            }, {
                type: 'Category',
                position: 'bottom',
                fields: ['name'],
                title: 'Sample Metrics'
            }],
            series: [{
                type: 'column',
                axis: 'left',
                highlight: true,
                tips: {
                    trackMouse: true,
                    width: 140,
                    height: 28,
                    renderer: function (storeItem, item) {
                        this.setTitle(storeItem.get('name') + ': ' + storeItem.get('data'));
                    }
                },
                label: {
                    display: 'insideEnd',
                    'text-anchor': 'middle',
                    field: 'data',
                    renderer: Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer('0'),
                    orientation: 'vertical',
                    color: '#333'
                },
                xField: 'name',
                yField: 'data'
            }]
        });

 //-----------------------------------------------Chart End Here------------------------------------------
    //-----------------------------------------Pie Chart Start Here---------------------------------------
    Ext.define('Chart', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: ['name', 'data']
    });

    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'Chart',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'json/PieChart.json',

            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'data'
            }
        },
        autoLoad: true
    });

    var piechart = Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        width: 300,
        height: 230,
        animate: true,
        //autoScroll: true,
        store: store,
        theme: 'Base:gradients',
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            angleField: 'data',
            showInLegend: true,

            tips: {
                trackMouse: true,
                width: 100,
                height: 28,

                renderer: function (storeItem, item) {
                    // calculate and display percentage on hover
                    var total = 0;
                    store.each(function (rec) {
                        total += rec.get('data');
                    });
                    this.setTitle(storeItem.get('name') + ': ' + Math.round(storeItem.get('data') / total * 100) + '%');
                }
            },
            highlight: {
                segment: {
                    margin: 10
                }
            },
            label: {
                field: 'name',
                display: 'rotate',
                contrast: true,
                font: '13px Arial Black'
            }
        }]
    });
    //-----------------------------------------Pie Chart End Here-----------------------------------------
    var one = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
                    title: 'Yield Curves',
                     url:'<img src="images/sencha.jpg" />',
                    // icon: 'images//sencha.jpg',
                    layout: 'card',
                    deferredRender: true,
                    title: 'first tab',
                    layout: {
                    type: 'hbox',
                    align: 'stretch',
                    padding: 10
                    },// configuring tab width
                    tabConfig: {
                        width: 250
                        },
                    defaults: {
                    flex: 1
                    },
                    items: [{
                    xtype: 'container',
                    margins: '0 5 0 0',
                    layout: {type: 'vbox',
                        align: 'stretch',
                        animate: true
                        },
                        defaults: {
                        flex: 1,
                        frame: true
                        },
                        items: [{
                        title: 'first',
                        margins: '0 0 5 0'
                        }, {
                        title: 'second',
                        items:[columndata]

                        }]
                        }, {
                        xtype: 'container',
                        layout: {
                        type: 'vbox',
                        align: 'stretch',
                        animate: true
                        },
                        defaults: {
                        flex: 1,
                        frame: true
                        },
                        items: [{
                        title: 'third',
                        items:[Panel],

                        margins: '0 0 5 0'
                        }, {
                        title: 'fourth',
                        items:[piechart]
                        }]
                        }]
                    });var two = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
                        title: 'FX Set',
                        layout: {
                        type: 'hbox',
                        align: 'stretch',
                        padding: 10
                        },
                        tabConfig: {
                            width: 250
                            },
                        defaults: {
                        flex: 1
                        },
                        items: [{
                        xtype: 'container',
                        margins: '0 5 0 0',
                        layout: {type: 'vbox',
                            align: 'stretch',
                            animate: true
                            },
                            defaults: {
                            flex: 1,
                            frame: true
                            },
                            items: [{
                            title: 'first',
                            margins: '0 0 5 0'
                            }, {
                            title: 'second',
                            items:[series]
                            }]
                            }]
                            });

                    var three = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
                        title: 'Market Data',
                        layout: {
                        type: 'hbox',
                        align: 'stretch',
                        padding: 10
                        },
                        tabConfig: {
                            width: 250

                            },
                        defaults: {
                        flex: 1
                        },
                        items: [{
                        xtype: 'container',
                        margins: '0 5 0 0',
                        layout: {type: 'vbox',
                            align: 'stretch',
                            animate: true
                            },
                            defaults: {
                            flex: 1,
                            frame: true
                            },
                            items: [{
                            title: 'first',
                            margins: '0 0 5 0',
                            width:1000
                            }, {
                            title: 'second'
                            }]
                            }, {
                            xtype: 'container',
                            layout: {
                            type: 'vbox',
                            align: 'stretch',
                            margins: '0 0 5 0',
                            animate: true
                            },
                            defaults: {
                            flex: 1,
                            frame: true
                            },
                            items: [{
                            title:'third',

                            margins: '0 0 5 0'
                            }/*, {
                            title: 'Purchase History'
                            }*/]
                            }]
                            });

                    var contentPanel = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
                                region: 'center',
                                margins: '0 5 5 0',
                                activeTab: 0,
                                collapsible: false,
                                autoScroll: true,
                                items: [one, two,three]
                                });
                            Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
                                layout: 'border',
                                items: [{
                                region: 'north',
                                margins: 5,
                                height: 20,
                                xtype: 'container',
                                //html: 'Logo Here'--> Only for text
                                // for inserting image this code

                                 html:'<marquee>'+'<blink>'+'Market Data Viewer'+'</blink>'+'</marquee>'+
                                "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"+
                                 "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"+
                                 "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"+
                                 "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"+
                                 "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"+
                                 "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"+
                                 "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"+
                                 "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"+
                                 "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"+new Date()
                                },
                                {
                                    xtype:'datefield',
                                    //label:'Date',
                                    format : 'm/d/Y h:i:s A'
                                    //value: new Date()
                                },/*mainMenu,*/ contentPanel]
                                });



});
```

Comment: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/guide/application_architecture

Comment: i want to change above code in EXTJS- MVC pattern

Comment: Are you serious? This needs more `&nbsp;`, `<marquee>` and `<blink>`.. On topic: what have you tried so far?

Comment: i'm new for extjs. right now i created this things in extjs. but i want to change this into MVC pattern

Comment: One very easy place to start is by using Sencha Cmd to generate the app structure for this app. The next easy step would be to take each of your "Ext.define(...)" blocks and create individual class files out of them (some in view, some in store). With that done, the majority of the work that will be left is binding everything together in a controller, or multiple controllers.